# Adobe Flex Filter XMLList

Tags: xml, apache-flex, adobe

Below is an excerpt from my XML file:

```
 <car>
  <carname>AC</carname>
  <carmodellist>
    <carmodel>Cobra</carmodel>
  </carmodellist>
</car>
```

How do I query the xmllistcollection and return all of the cars in the carmodellist where carname == 'AC'?

I've tried several combinations without luck, I'm thinking it would be something similar to this:

```
var models:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(vehicles.child(@car=='AC').carmodellist.children());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have xml like following:

```
<cars>
    <car>
        <carname>AC</carname>
        <carmodellist>
            <carmodel>Cobra</carmodel>
            <carmodel>Cobra2</carmodel>
        </carmodellist>
    </car>
    <car>
        <carname>AB</carname>
        <carmodellist>
            <carmodel>Bobra</carmodel>
        </carmodellist>
    </car>
    <car>
        <carname>AD</carname>
        <carmodellist>
            <carmodel>Dobra</carmodel>
        </carmodellist>
    </car>
</cars>
```

Then:

```
vehicles.car.(carname == 'AC').carmodellist.children()
```

Comment: vehicles.car.(carname == 'AC') will be an XMLList. Except you have only 1 node of carname = AC you will end up in a runtime error.

Comment: @Adrian Pirvulescu I don't see any problems here

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give this a shot and let you know what I come up with.

Comment: Looks like this was what worked in the end:

new XMLListCollection(xmlVehicles.children().(carname==o.carname).carmodellist.children());

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik There is no problem in your current example. But if you replace <carname>AB</carname> with <carname>AC</carname> you will see what I mean. ;) Sure maybe out of context at this point... just commented you need to pay attention to it, I did not say your solution is wrong.